# Colab resources and Self-Attention (OOM when allocating tensor)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network, attention-model

I'm trying to implement a self-Attention GAN on google Colab with Keras. When i test my Attention Layer i've got a OOM error. So, am i doing something wrong with matrix multiplications or its just a too expensive operation for colab GPU at higher resolutions (> 64 x 64)?

```
def hw_flatten(x):
   # Input shape x: [BATCH, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS]
   # flat the feature volume across the width and height dimensions 

   x = Reshape((x.shape[1]*x.shape[2], x.shape[3]))(x) #in the Reshape layer batch is implicit

   return x # return [BATCH, W*H, CHANNELS]



def matmul(couple_t):
  tensor_1 = couple_t[0]
  tensor_2 = couple_t[1]
  transponse = couple_t[2] #boolean 

  return tf.matmul(tensor_1, tensor_2, transpose_b=transponse)



class SelfAttention(Layer):

  def _init_(self, ch, **kwargs):
    super(SelfAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.ch = ch

  
  def attentionMap(self, feature_map):

    f = Conv2D(filters=feature_map.shape[3]/8, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=1, padding='same')(feature_map) # [bs, h, w, c']
    g = Conv2D(filters=feature_map.shape[3]/8, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=1, padding='same')(feature_map) # [bs, h, w, c']
    h = Conv2D(filters=feature_map.shape[3], kernel_size=(1,1), strides=1, padding='same')(feature_map)   # [bs, h, w, c']

    s = Lambda(matmul)([hw_flatten(g), hw_flatten(f), True]) # [bs, N, N]
    beta = Activation("softmax")(s)

    o = Lambda(matmul)([beta, hw_flatten(h), False]) # [bs, N, C]


    gamma = self.add_weight(name='gamma', shape=[1], initializer='zeros', trainable=True)

    o = Reshape((feature_map.shape[1:]))(o) # [bs, h, w, C]

    x = gamma * o + feature_map

    print(x.shape)

    return x
```

This is the test:

```
tensor = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(32, 64, 64, 512)).astype('float64')
attention_o = SelfAttention(64)
a = attention_o.attentionMap(tensor)
```

This is the error:

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,4096,4096] and type double
```

Thank you so much for your Attention :D

Answer (score 2):

Your tensor of size 32x4096x4096 has 536870912 entries! This, multiplied by the number of bytes in a double (8), and converted to Gb is 4294! That is over 4Tb, and definitely will not fit in a GPU. You might want to add in a few max pooling layers to reduce the dimensionality of your data before applying self-attention.

Comment: So, If i want to apply self-attention layer at the end of Generator (128x128) i have to, for example: use max-pooling two times (32x32) -> apply attention -> Upsample (128x128). Does it make sense? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. I would definitely apply some convolutional layers before each max pooling operation, so the neural network can learn compressed representations of the data.